# How to pass a JSON decoded Array to another VC on swift

Tags: json, swift, tableview

well Im trying to pass an array of articles which came from a news API to another VC so I will be able to display them on my TableView, now the problem is that the tableview is loaded before I updated my array, is there a way to update the array before the tableview is loaded?

MY CODE:
MY NewsViewController Code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class NewsViewController: UITableViewController,NewsProtocol {
    
    func didUpdateNewsArr(arr: [Articles]) {
        newsArr = arr
        print("I'm loaded first!!")
//        print(newsArr[0].title)
    }
    

    var newsArr = [Articles]()
    
    var newsManager =  NewsManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.title = "Hot News"
        newsManager.newsProtocolDelegate = self
        newsManager.performRequest()

        
        
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        
    }
}





// MARK: - UITableView Delegate&DataSource Methods:
extension NewsViewController {
   
    // Return the number of rows for the table.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newsArr.count
    }

    // Provide a cell object for each row.
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       // Fetch a cell of the appropriate type.
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newsCell", for: indexPath)
       
       // Configure the cell’s contents.
       cell.textLabel!.text = "Cell text"
           
       return cell
    }
    
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
    }
}
```

my networking file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol NewsProtocol {
    func didUpdateNewsArr(arr: [Articles])
}


struct NewsManager {
    let newsURL = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=apple&from=2020-10-19&to=2020-10-19&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=009a08a56d664f1b92986e9cce27767b"
    
    var newsProtocolDelegate: NewsProtocol?
    
    
    func performRequest() {
        if let url = URL(string: newsURL) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, respone, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    self.parseJSON(newsData: safeData)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    func parseJSON(newsData: Data) {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(NewsData.self, from: newsData)
            let articlesArr = decodedData.articles
            newsProtocolDelegate?.didUpdateNewsArr(arr: articlesArr)
            
        } catch {
            print("")
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: The table loads in less than 0.1s, the network request likely takes longer, you can either request in advance the data so by the time the user opens that screen you have the data, or reload the table view once you receive the data.

Comment: You need to reload tableview data, Once data is being loaded from API.

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad ye but where do I need to tableview.reload() ?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem :) thanks fellas, all was needed was tableView.reload() to reload the cells, due to the fact that the JSON request took a while and the tableView was made up before the request, I've used DispatchQue :)